# Interacting with custom elements in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, custom-element

I have created a custom element. 
Where I am passing input parameters to the application.

```html
<custom-element-demo 
  domain="https://google.com"
  secret1='2eqwuiqg713gubejkqgefiuugqehfui'
  secret2='sdsafuh13iughkebgwidfwefwefdsdg'
  >
</custom-element-demo>
```

My next extending requirement for the same is that I should be able to create application using only java script.

Similar to what [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) has already achieved using reactjs

```js
<script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
```

Here they have also created custom element but on top of it they are able to pass all data simply using script tag. No html required just one div "bot" which they are trying to refer to.

Comment: This isn't helpful? https://angular.io/guide/elements#typings-for-custom-elements